is there a way to keep initialized structs outside loop?
I am learning c/c++ by myself, when making a program to read a file format from a game, I was able to get the data needed, but the problem is, it is only accessible while inside the loop that reads it. I am not able to use it anywhere else in the function much less outside it.
i know variables and etc "disappear" after the loop, but im using dynamic memory allocation using "new" method, its an array of structs. i cant initialize it beforehand cause the amount of elements is unknown without reading the file first.
i need this information for later use, so if it just lives while inside the loop, thats useless really...
heres my code
typedef struct {
    uint32_t FbxHash;
    string ShapeName;
    float ShapeTransforms[18];
    bool converted;
} ShapeEntity;

and the function that reads the file:
void CompositeMeshReader(FILE* MeshCompPtr) {
    uint8_t NumberOfLods;
    uint8_t NumberOfMeshes;
    uint8_t ShadersPerMesh;
    float GlobalTransforms[6];
    int NumberOfShapes;
    int CurrentLOD;
    int w;
    int y;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    string fname;
    string* fnameptr = &fname;
    uint8_t z;
    uint8_t NullProperty;
    uint8_t UnknownByte;
    bool stay = true;


    fseek(MeshCompPtr, 5, SEEK_SET);
    StringSkipper(fnameptr);
    cout << "Lods Settings File: " << fname << endl;
    fread(&NumberOfLods, 1, 1, MeshCompPtr);
    fseek(MeshCompPtr, 3, SEEK_CUR);
    cout << "Lods detected: " << int(NumberOfLods) << ", which one to extract?" << endl;
    cout << "for lod 0, type 0, lod 1, type 1, etc" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    fname = "";
    CurrentLOD = 0;
    while ((CurrentLOD < NumberOfLods) && (stay == true)) {
        fread(&NullProperty, 1, 1, MeshCompPtr);
        fread(&ShadersPerMesh, 1, 1, MeshCompPtr);
        fread(&NumberOfMeshes, 1, 1, MeshCompPtr);

        for (j = 0; j < NumberOfMeshes; j++) {
            StringSkipper(fnameptr);
            if (i == CurrentLOD) {
                cout << "Mesh " << j << " " << fname << endl << endl;
            }
            for (k = 0; k < ShadersPerMesh; k++) {
                StringSkipper(fnameptr);
                if (i == CurrentLOD) {
                    cout << "Shader " << k << " " << fname << endl << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        fread(GlobalTransforms, sizeof GlobalTransforms[0], 6, MeshCompPtr);
        fseek(MeshCompPtr, 8, SEEK_CUR);
        fread(&UnknownByte, 1, 1, MeshCompPtr);
        fread(&NumberOfShapes, 4, 1, MeshCompPtr);
        ShapeEntity* Shapes = new ShapeEntity[NumberOfShapes]; // this is what I need to keep alive
        for (w = 0; w < NumberOfShapes; w++) {
            fread(&Shapes[w].FbxHash, 4, 1, MeshCompPtr);
            StringSkipper(fnameptr);
            Shapes[w].ShapeName = fname;
            fread(Shapes[w].ShapeTransforms, 4, 18, MeshCompPtr);
            Shapes[w].converted = false;
        }
        fseek(MeshCompPtr, ShadersPerMesh * 24, SEEK_CUR);
        if (i != CurrentLOD) {
            cout << "Shapes destroyed" << endl;
            delete[] Shapes; 
        }
        else {
            print(Shapes, ShadersPerMesh, NumberOfMeshes, NumberOfShapes, GlobalTransforms);
            stay = false;
            
        }
        CurrentLOD++;
    }
    return;
}

im trying to keep Shapes alive even after returning from this function, but after leaving the while loop they just disappear, im just going nuts this seems to be impossible? without rewritting the whole thing from scratch
looked pretty much everywhere but still cant find a proper solution to this

Your code is C++.  Do not add the C tag.  Don't try to learn both languages at once.  They are very different and idiomatic C++ simply won't compile in C and idiomatic C is bad C++ code.

Learning C++ on your own is tricky. If you had a good source of information then it would have told you about std::vector, this code is absolutely crying out for that. A good source would also have told you that it you want to keep something alive after a function has exited then the usual way to do that is return the item you want to keep from the function.

That's a mess. Break up your function into about 10 smaller ones. Don't use new and delete and C-style arrays. void CompositeMeshReader(FILE* MeshCompPtr) can only influence the file passed in and global variables (and you should not use global variables), so think about changing the signature. Prefer C++ streams over C-style FILE*.

typedef struct { /*...*/ } ShapeEntity; is also a C idiom that doesn't make sense in C++ where it is equivalent to struct ShapeEntity { /*...*/ }: and nobody uses the former except when writing code to interoperate between C and C++ code.

Since you are teaching yourself (and it seems you don't have a good book) have a look at https://learncpp.com, the best C++ tutorial on the net. Start by reading their lesson on vectors.

ShapeEntity* Shapes = new ShapeEntity[NumberOfShapes]; // this is what I need to keep alive --> Idiomatic C++ would have done this: std::vector<ShapeEntity> CompositeMeshReader(FILE* MeshCompPtr) {...std::vector<ShapeEntity> Shapes(NumberOfShapes);...return Shapes; }

but im using dynamic memory allocation using "new" method, its an array of structs. i cant initialize it beforehand cause the amount of elements is unknown without reading the file first. -- Don't do this.  As mentioned, the std::vector container does all of this already.

"I am learning c/c++ by myself" -- First, this is not the most important thing for people to know to answer your question (your question is most important). So this information should be at the end of your question or omitted altogether. Second, Learn C or C++, not both. Once you learn one, learning the other should be easier since the language structure is similar. However, if you tackle both at once, you're likely to confuse yourself, since the language structure is not identical.

I started this 1 week ago...had some knowledge because I debugged some crackmes but i will try to fix it using vectors...thanks

"im trying to keep Shapes alive even after returning from this function" -- This looks like the start of a [mre]. Forget everything else this function is supposed to do. Focus on the lifetime of Shapes. Drop the file, drop the configuration, drop everything but creating something for Shapes and... whatever it is you intend to use to access it after the function returns. This question is not your program. Think abstractly, and get to the essence of your question.

Either return shapes (or pass it in as a reference) or use a global variable for it (which may hurt you later if you need multithreading or run into some issues with dynamically linked libraries). As your function is written, it just leaks the memory (allocates the memory but then never deletes it as you don't pass the pointer to anywhere else).
Also, if you are using C++, it's much better to use something like an std::vector for this rather than a raw pointer to a dynamically allocated array, as then you won't run into the memory leaks. Your code is basically C code as is, not really C++.

Note that global variables can hurt you in many more different ways than are described her. My personal favorite is because the value of a global variable can be changed by any part of the program for any reason at any time, when debugging all parts of the code may have side effects that need to be taken into account. Now instead of investigating a limited number of paths through the code, you may find yourself having to investigate ALL of the code. And that sucks up time.

@user4581301 to be fair, that's kind of the point of global variables, that any code that needs them can use them. Yes, they have costs (we've touched on a few), but they also have some benefits (avoiding a bunch of extra function parameters to pass in what could otherwise be a global variable that the linker deals with for you, and potentially extra optimizations based on the compiler knowing there's only the one global object). Whether the costs are worth it depends on the particular problem (reading meshes suggests to me "no" unless there will only ever be a single mesh - then "maybe")
